# Como fazer referencia a uma biblioteca externa?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll, biblioteca, nuget

Tenho um projeto em Asp.Net MVC onde gostaria de adicionar algumas bibliotecas novas.

Elas estão disponíveis para download como `.dll`, mas também estão disponíveis no **Manage NuGet Packages**.

Qual a melhor maneira de adicionar a biblioteca ao projeto, adicionando a `dll` em algum diretório do projeto e fazendo referencia ou instalando via **NuGet**?

Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens?
Quais são os riscos?

Comment: eu gosto de usar via NuGet, assim quando preciso baixar o projeto ele carrega as dependências automaticamente.
NuGet veio para ficar!!!!

Comment: NuGet: Quais são as vantagens? R.: Gerenciamento das dependências automaticamente. Mas e as desvantagens? Existem?
Quais são os riscos? Existem? Por que não usar o outro método?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso varia um pouco conforme o gosto do(s) desenvolvedor(es) do projeto.

## Nuget

Ao instalar um pacote com o nuget, existem algumas vantagens. As principais delas são:

1. É (muito) simples atualizar suas bibliotecas.

   Digamos que você use a biblioteca [Atlassian SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Atlassian.SDK). Para atualizá-la usando referência simples você deverá baixar a nova DLL, remover a DLL antiga e adicionar a nova DLL ao projeto. Agora imagine o seguinte, esta biblioteca faz uso de outra biblioteca, a [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/), e o pessoal que faz o Atlassian SDK está usando uma versão mais recente do RestSharp. O que você vai ter que fazer? Isso mesmo, baixar a nova versão do RestSharp, excluir a referência antiga e adicionar a nova referência.

   Se você estiver usando o Nuget, precisa digitar isso no *Package Manager Console*

   > PM> update-package Atlassian.SDK

   E o Nuget irá automaticamente baixar a nova dll, remover a antiga referência, criar a nova referência e atualizar as dependências. Mágico, não?
2. Você não precisa adicionar binários ao seu projeto.

   Ao invés do Nuget deixar as dlls de suas bibliotecas como parte de seu projeto, ele cria um arquivo `packages.config` onde guarda as informações necessárias para baixar os binários posteriormente e cria uma pasta `/packages` fora do escopo do projeto. Esse arquivo `.config` contém todas as referências do seu projeto. Ex.: Você tem um projeto no [GitHub](http://github.com). Este projeto faz uso de 12 bibliotecas, todas adicionadas pelo Nuget e você optou por não upar os binários das bibliotecas para o repositório. Quando alguém baixar o projeto, abrir com o Visual Studio e der *build* o Nuget se encarregará de fazer o download de todas as bibliotecas referenciadas no arquivo `packages.config` e de adicioná-las ao projeto. (Para isso a opção `Allow Nuget to download missing packages` deve estar ativada).

A única desvantagem que eu consigo ver no Nuget é que, **talvez**, um dia esse serviço será descontinuado e você pode ficar sem seus pacotes. Ou então que você pode ficar sem atualizar suas bibliotecas caso o serviço fique temporariamente fora do ar.

Answer (score 5):

Caso você instale as bibliotecas via `Nuget Package` as referências serão automaticamente criadas para você; o repositório físico dos pacotes será criado fora do escopo do projeto em si.

Isso permite que você compartilhe projetos, deixando ao encargo do *Nuget Manager* o trabalho de realizar o download dos pacotes presentes no seu projeto.

No caso de *Assemblies* que não possuem *nuget packages*, fica a seu critério; para fins de organização eu geramente as coleto em um diretório no projeto chamado `ext`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda @OnoSendai, mas quais seriam os benefício em um ambiente com TFS ou GIT por exemplo? Existe algum risco em alguma das duas práticas no processo de remoção da biblioteca?

Comment: O benefício seria que você não armazena conteúdo binário desnecessário no repositório. Entretanto, o risco sempre existe - um dia no futuro (provavelmente) distante o serviço NuGet será descontinuado, e você ficará sem seus pacotes. Por isso é sempre bom fazer um backup periódico do package storage.

Comment: Muito obrigado @OnoSendai, era exatamente isso que eu precisava saber! Se tiver mais coisa e puder ir enchendo a resposta com sua sabedoria, rsrsrs...